# Is it possible to pass parameters between web performance tests in visual studio 2013?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, performance-testing

Lets assume that we have two web performance tests a and b as described below:

- TestA: Login to page A.com
- TestB: will call TestA, and do some more stuff. Further assume that this page needs to be tested against site A.com and B.com (the credentials for A.com and B.Com are the same).

Is it possible to pass a URL parameter (which might be either A.com or B.com) from the testB to the testA? In such a way that the testA instead of loading the page A.com, loads the page B.com. Basically I want to be flexible, and be able to pass the URL parameter over. Having said that, I should still be able to execute the testA standalone as well (going to A.com). So basically A.com should be the default value, and if required, it should be possible to be overwritten.

If it is possible, what do I need to do?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

If one test calls another via the "Insert call to web test" command in the web test editor, then the context of the calling test is made available to the called test. So data can be passed from caller to called. (I am not sure whether the called test can pass values back to the caller via the context. I will have to check and update this answer in the future.)

---

If the web tests are called from a load test then another method is available.
One of the context parameters of a web test that is called from a load test is the load test context. In the web test the value of this context parameter can be cast to a [load test context](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.loadtesting.loadtestcontext.aspx). Then values can be written into the context by one test and read out in another.

Comment: Yes, that is going to work, but if you have a load test. However, what if you don't have the load test to control the web tests? As I mentioned above, two separate performance tests, and one will be called in the second one (don't have the load test). How can I pass parameters to the called web performance test?

Comment: @user2585405 How are you calling one test from the other?

Comment: Insert Call to Web Test... Option in a performance test will do the job for you or you can modify the code and call it as well. But in my case I used the first one (the visual studio functionality)

Answer (score 0):

for context parameters:
any parameter created in the calling test is available in the called test.
and the reverse is true as well.
to use the parameter, just reference it by name
if the parameter has been created in several tests, the one that runs first will override the others
eg:

have 3 tests, a,b,c. 
 A is primary and calls B and then calls C
 context parameter x is created in A only, and so is usable in A and B.
 context parameter y is created in B and C, and is usable in A (after B runs) and the B value overrides the C value.
 context parameter z is created in both A and B and C. the value in A overrides all others.

for extracted context parameters:
whichever is extracted last will override all previous instances.
and if the variable is not usable in another test, create a context parameter with the same name in that test, and that parameter will be overwritten by the extracted value during execution.